# Bind dynamically created User Controls Image and Text height to Grid Cell height WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that has a grid that stretches with the window. Here is my Main Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFProjekt.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFProjekt"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="661.282" Width="808.205">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,19,8">
        <Grid x:Name="mygrid" Margin="10,0,421,0">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/img/1200px-Football_pitch.svg.png"  TileMode="Tile"></ImageBrush>

            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to dynamically generate User Controls with an Image and a TextBlock inside the Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFProjekt.PlayerCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFProjekt"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/img/Facebook-default-no-profile-pic.jpg" Margin="0,-53,547,63" MinWidth="250" MinHeight="285" >
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Facebook-default-no-profile-pic.jpg"/>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
        <TextBlock Text="Some text" Margin="0,331,0,10" FontSize="36"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the code for the Main Window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
 
    ColumnDefinition c = new ColumnDefinition();
    c.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);

    for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
    { 
        PlayerCtrl playerControl = new PlayerCtrl();

        Grid.SetRow(playerControl, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(playerControl, 0);

        mygrid.Children.Add(playerControl);
    }
}
```

How do I bind the font size from the textblock and the height of the image to the cell height? They need to be generated in code behind because the control placement in the grid varies depending on the users actions.

Comment: The UserControl would usually expose bindable properties, i.e. dependency properties. The elements in its XAML would bind to those properties like `<Image Height="{Binding ImageHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" .../>`. For the FontSize, you could simply bind the UserControl's FontSize, as the property value is inherited by the child elements.

Comment: from my knowing, the image automatically stretches to the according cell if you provide an Aspect attribute such as `Aspect="AspectFill"`

Comment: @julian that appears to be Xamarin. In WPF you could set Stretch.

Comment: May we see your code for your user control? I am trying to run your code.